# My ajax upload csv file with spanish letters in utf-8 charset cut my registers

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax, csv

We have very issues with charset and collations solved definetly. 
All transactions we had troubles were a headache but we solved in ajax,html and php in mysql database, finally we solved all troubles at last.

But we make an ajax csv upload (with only ; for separate the fields) with any
spanish letter (ñÑáéíóú)  the field cut when upload when find those letters.

this is my functional upload called from my ajax :

```
  if(!empty($_FILES['fileajax']['name'])){

   try {

  $DB = new Db(DBHost,DBName,DBUser,DBPassword);      
  $output = "";

  $allowed_ext = array("csv");

  $tmp = explode('.', $_FILES['fileajax']['name']);
  $extension = end($tmp);


  if(in_array($extension,$allowed_ext)){
    $file_data = fopen($_FILES['fileajax']['tmp_name'],"r");
    fgetcsv($file_data, 10000, ";");
    while($row = fgetcsv($file_data)){

      $datos = explode(";",$row[0]);

      $values = array(
        addslashes($datos[0]),
        addslashes($datos[1]),
        addslashes($datos[2]),          
        addslashes($datos[3]),          
        date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($datos[4])),          
        date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($datos[5])),          
        date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
        date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
        $_SESSION['sess_username_id'],
        $_SESSION['sess_username_id']
      );

      $DB->query("INSERT INTO table (idP, num, nom, can, inio, mino, rt, tiate, idUate, idUrt) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", $values);//Parameters must be ordered

      var_dump($values);
    }
  }else{
    echo "error1";
  }





}catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo $this->ExceptionLog($e->getMessage());
  die();
}


  }else{
    echo "error2";
  }
```

and our ajax is:

```
$('#upload_csv').on('submit',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#preloader').fadeIn('slow');

  $.ajax({
    url: "acciones/importItem.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: new FormData(this),
    contentType:false,
    cache: false,
    processData:false,
    success: function (data){
      //console.log(data);
      if(data == 'error1'){
        toastr.error('Archivo no valido...', 'Cargar partida', {timeOut: 1500});
      }else if(data == 'error2'){
        toastr.error('Seleccione Archivo...', 'Cargar partida', {timeOut: 1500});
      }else{
        toastr.success('Partidas cargadas exitosamente...', 'Cargar partida', {timeOut: 1500});
      $('#modalSubirItem').modal('hide');
      location.reload();



      }
    }


  });
  $('#preloader').fadeOut('slow');

});
```

Really i think that we forgeting someting in upload configuration.

This is my file to upload (saved as csv filetype(please make your csv with this)): jsfiddle in html appartment!!

https://jsfiddle.net/x7e2am5c/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks theo for your help.

The code you bring me `setlocale(LC_ALL, "es_ES.UTF-8");` make no difference in the upload result, but was a guide for the solution that was add php array map with the utf8_encode.

The following code modification was the solution for the CSV ajax upload :

```
 while($row = fgetcsv($file_data)){
      $row = array_map("utf8_encode", $row);//adding this line solve the problem
      $datos = explode(";",$row[0]);

      $values = array(
        addslashes($datos[0]),
        ...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think `fgetcsv()` is the culprit here.
Because it uses the Locale settings, UTF-8 files may be read in wrong.

In this case

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "es_ES.UTF-8");
```

may do the trick